# jQuery vegas plugin heavy on ram

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, jquery-plugins

I have been searching everywhere and do not seem to be able to find anyone else reporting the same issue.

I'm currently building a website that is using the jQuery vegas plugin but I started noticing that if I kept the page opened while developing and testing, my computer starts slowing down drastically. I started monitoring my task manager and the memory used by the browser goes up every time the slideshow moves to the next image and just keeps going up non-stop.

I've tried with IE 11, firefox 27 and Chrome 33 and the problem only seems to happen with google Chrome. However, using Chrome, if I go on the official plugin website (http://vegas.jaysalvat.com/) where they do use the plugin, I do not experience the problem.

Here are the links to jQuery and the plugin:

`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>`

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jaysalvat.github.io/vegas/releases/latest/jquery.vegas.min.js"></script>`

Here is my js code:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

    $.vegas('slideshow', {
        delay:10000,
        preload:true,
        backgrounds: [
            {src:'images/bg_body-001.png', fade:2000},
            {src:'images/bg_body-002.png', fade:2000},
            {src:'images/bg_body-003.png', fade:2000},
            {src:'images/bg_body-004.png', fade:2000},
            {src:'images/bg_body-005.png', fade:2000}
        ]
    });


});
```

Comment: A link to the plugin would be beneficial. As well as jquery version, plugin version, and browsers tested

Comment: Sorry, I realise I wasn't very elaborate. I edited my question and included more details. Thanks

Comment: Does the issue happen if you turn preload off? Can you make a [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) using your images?

Comment: Yep, whether it's on or off, there is no difference. It seems as if it's loading the images in the memory over and over

Answer (score 0):

Are you testing your code in a local hard drive? I had this problem too, but I solved it by moving the same website from my local hard drive to a webserver. I'd suggest trying this and testing again, and hopefully this will help you too.

Comment: Yeah I was testing it locally and the issue only happened when testing locally